# google map api hello world

Tags: html, google-maps

I'm learning Google map api v3. So I went to their site and found the Helloworld from the developers' guide:
link:[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I replaced the API_KEY by an api key and SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE by true. But my browser gave me:

```
This page contains the following errors:error on line 12 at column 96:
 EntityRef:expecting';'Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Could someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Share the tutorial link?

Comment: Did you replace the `SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE` too?

Comment: @sabotero Yes forgot to mention. I replace it by true

Comment: The code as posted works for me if I remove the key (it is not required) and change SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE to false (shouldn't matter which it is as long as it is correct and one of the two valid values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the link below.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8FSWj/

There is no need to set API key in the script. Please use script used in the above demo.

You have to set div height and width in pixels. Do not set div height and width in percentage.

Another demo with zip code search as below.

**Search Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/y829C/1/

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

#map_canvas{
    height: 350px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to deal with the Google Map API. I'm definitely no expert but..

If you remove the API key all together and replace **sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE** with **sensor=false** it 'should' work fine.

I'm not sure what the repercussions are for not using an API key though.

Check it out here: http://jsbin.com/aHuKiJIm/1/